# Gym for a 14 year old?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, muscle

So I'm skinny, and I began going to the gym, I started first weekends doing very small weight (5 kilos) but in a correct form, doing 4 series of 15 reps for every exercise/machine I did/used, I don't really know if you can get strenght that fast, but now like after a month and a half I were doing all the way up to 22 kilos for back and chest, and for arms and legs about 10-16 kilos. I read that you could only charge up to 50% of your weight, 22 it's close, but anyways some guy told me some things like:

1. I would damage my articulations (believable and actually true)
2. Energy used for growing would go to the muscles regeneration (I eat more since I started going to the gym)

So I ended up doing 17 kilos 30 reps, because with 11 kilos I was just going to do like 100 reps until beginning to feel the muscle working. Should I do insanity or should I keep doing what I'm doing, obviously I'm not gonna grow up crazy muscle, so I don't really care a lot about that part altough I would like to see results lol. And also it's true that I won't grow up? I'm near 5'11 but I want to grow more lol.

Answer (score 1):

While it's widely known that lifting stunts growth, it seems likely it's actually a myth. The main thing is that you don't go on some crazy diet, because then your body won't be getting energy and nutrition to grow.

http://www.livestrong.com/article/430166-can-lifting-weights-when-young-stunt-your-growth/#page=1

> According to Dr. Avery Faigenbaum of the University of Massachusetts, concerns about weight lifting stunting the growth of children and adolescents are outdated and misleading. Instead, he suggests that eating a healthy diet and exercising regularly allow you to achieve your maximal height, with inactive, unhealthy eaters more likely to have stunted growth. Betsy Keller of Ithaca College suggests that this myth exists because some researchers focus only on specific groups of athletes. In a 2008 review of the literature, she suggests that evidence for weightlifting's negative impact on growth arises solely from sports that are well-suited for shorter people, such as women's gymnastics and competitive dancing.

http://scoobysworkshop.com/bodybuilding-stunts-growth/

> I often get questions from teens asking if bodybuilding will stunt their growth, the answer is ‘No!‘....

http://www.bodybuilding.com/teen/jay1.htm

> One of the biggest myths about weightlifting is that it stunts your growth. No studies have ever been shown that lifting weights stunts or inhibitsgrowth. But, as with any exercise program, if you do too much too soon, physical problems can occur no matter how old the person doing the exercise is.

Just to point out, doing 30 won't be building much muscles, aim for less reps (like 15) but heavier weights.
And be very careful, certain exercises can be damaging, especially if done incorrectly, so get someone experienced to watch you during a workout one time.

You asked about doing insanity. If your fairly fit and your just looking to stay in shape, then I don't see why gym isn't enough. If the gym isn't working, then you can try it. But speak to someone who knows you and your situation better.

Comment: Thanks, finnaly someone who answered, I mean I reached my "max weight" and I can't lift more cause I would damage my articulations, so im doing 30 reps, cause 15 wasn't just enough to feel my muscle crying lol